# Can't sign in to FB using Tor on iPhone

Tags: help

I can't sign in to Facebook through Tor on my iPhone. I have no problem on my desktop or laptop, however. Suggestions?

Comment: What URL do you use to access Facebook? What software do you use on your iPhone? Please add more information to your question. Right now it is unclear what the problem is and this makes it hard to give a good answer.